# Ansible Parallel and pre-conditoons

Tags: ansible

I have a strategy question regarding parallel execution of `ansible-playbook` on the same machine.
So we have 3 parallel runs on the same playbook triggered by Jenkins jobs.

Example:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/hosts --vault-password-file **** -e CLIENT=test1 
ansible-playbook -i inventories/hosts --vault-password-file **** -e CLIENT=test2 
ansible-playbook -i inventories/hosts --vault-password-file **** -e CLIENT=test3
```

They run on parallel!

Each 3 of them check if the certain yum packages are installed during yum task.

What is the issue?

The problem is that if the yum installation happens in the same time while another yum installation is running, it will result in a yum lock.
So how can I make sure that YUM task is installed only once like as a pre-condition?

Comment: Don't run thee playbook in parallel. Paas the parameters as a list to a single playbook and have the yum task install all three packages in a single run. This is by far more performant and you don't have to deal with the yum lock (as far as your // runs are concerned).

Comment: But then it will install the playbook to different environments one by one. Wouldn't that be much slower than parallel?

Comment: Will it be slower than hitting a race condition which fails your install? Moveover, in your scenario (i.e. installing a list of packages), this will be done in one single run and will be faster that installing each package independently, even in //. Unless I did not get your problem at all, [this is basically what you should do](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/46b975a12b297af27bb35bb9431d6d6b)